# parallel downloading of videos from several ip camras using java

Tags: java

I am building an application which downloads files from around 100 ip cameras paralelly over the network throught the day. The files in the camera are of length 1 minute varying around 1.5 to 2.5 Mb in size. Each of the files takes around 10 to 20 secs to download. The server I am using, has a four-core processeor with 8GB of RAM. The task is to download 1 file from each of the cameras per minute (60 files per hour) for 24x7.

First I tried by creaing as many threads as the number of cameras. This worked well for a relatively small number of cameras but as the numbers increased, I found that the number of files getting downloaded per camera is very less. Even in some days, the downloading is entirely missed for certain cameras. This I thought might be because I am creating one thread per camera, ie around 100 threads, some of the threads might not be getting the CPU at all. So I tried a second method.

I kept the number of threads same as that of the number of cores ie 4. So, all the cameras are handled by only four cores. This was done to ensure that the cameras are not getting missed. The code for this was done using the Executer class in Java handling a pool of four threads. As is the case, the files got downloaded from all the cameras. But now, the number of files getting downloaded per camera is very less. That is, in an hour, the server can download only around 15 files from each camera, while it is supposed to download 60 files in an hour (as each file is of duration one minute). This can be attributed to the fact that, each thread is handling 25 cameras, and the downloading performed by a particular thread is sequential. That is each thread will serially take up one of the 25 cameras and download from it before taking on the next. And each file takes around 15 secs on an average to get downloaded.

That network bandwidth is very high for the server but the network is slow in the camera side where it has got around 256 to 512 Kbps.

How should I optimize the code or the server config so as to download all the files from the camera. Moreover, the files in the camera are formed in real time, so I have go a single minute to download the files from all the cameras, otherwise, files will get skipped.

Comment: Are those `Mb` and `kbps` the right units of measure? I mean, are all expressed in bits?

Comment: @watery: its all in bits

Comment: May be you should use async/multiplexed/Non blocking IO. Where in, each thread downloads from multiple cameras at the same time.

Comment: @Venkata: I am reading about AsynchronousFileChannel in java. I have never used it before. I think it is mainly used for reading and writing from and to large files. Will this be a good idea for multiple file download ?

Comment: @Soumya I believe so. You may want to use libraries like https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client